# Why is my Data sent as Undefined when using Tabulator?

Tags: javascript, html, json, tabulator

I am trying to insert JSON data that are supposed to be search results into my Tabulator, which is then supposed to display the search results in their respective columns. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div>
<script>

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://hadrians-search.tk/search",
    ajaxParams:{search_param:"ball", items_per_page:"2", page_number:"2"},
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

    return response.Object; //return the d property of a response json object
    },  
    columns:
        [{title:"Title", field:"shippingCost.title"},
        {title:"Price", field:"price"},
        {title:"Shipping Cost", field:"shippingCost.shippingServiceCost.value"},
        {title:"Shipping Type", field:"shippingCost.shippingServiceCost.shippingType"},
    ],
});
</script>
</body>
```

I am receiving this in the Console tab of my browser:

```
Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type 
Expecting: array 
Received:  undefined 
Data:      undefined tabulator.min.js:2:29478
 n.prototype._setDataActual
 https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js:2:29478
 n.prototype.setData/<
 https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js:2:28800
 n.prototype.setData
 https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js:2:28624
 f.prototype._loadDataStandard/</<
 https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js:5:7539
```

This is the JSON Response I am sending to the Tabulator:

```
{
  "0": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "323440622675",
    "price": "11.02",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "false",
      "handlingTime": "3",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "Magnetic Pearl Ball Curtain Tiebacks Tie Backs Holdbacks Buckle Clips Accessory",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "country": "CN",
    "itemId": "332746804737",
    "price": "2.49",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "false",
      "handlingTime": "1",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "Natural Amethyst Quartz Stone Sphere Crystal Fluorite Ball Healing Gemstone",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "322315462251",
    "price": "5.49",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "1",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "4.89"
      },
      "shippingType": "Flat"
    },
    "title": "Richardson Trucker Ball Cap Meshback Hat Snapback Cap Trucker Hat Cap - 112",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "183411812494",
    "price": "22.99",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "0",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "Seismic Sports Slam Ball 10 - 30 lb Slam Ball for Crossfit, HIIT, Plyometrics",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "113179929571",
    "price": "20.89",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "1",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "true",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "3 In 1 Kids Baby Play Tent Ball Pit Pool House Crawl Tunnel Indoor Outdoor Game",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "5": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "153249589978",
    "price": "10.34",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "1",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "Premium Official Size 5 USA Soccer Ball W/ Pump Assorted Graphics!",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "6": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "153168623537",
    "price": "58.99",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "1",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "Dragon Ball The Complete Series Seasons 1-5 - 1,2,3,4,5 New",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "7": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "110874290750",
    "price": "9.41",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "1",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "true",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "FlatDomesticCalculatedInternational"
    },
    "title": "5006 Flexfit Sweep Low Profile Fitted Baseball Blank Plain Hat Ball Cap Flex Fit",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "8": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "332908229449",
    "price": "39.99",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "2",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "ADIDAS BRAZUCA OFFICIAL MATCH BALL AUTHENTIC WORLD CUP 2014",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  },
  "9": {
    "country": "US",
    "itemId": "282781534125",
    "price": "13.99",
    "shippingCost": {
      "expeditedShipping": "true",
      "handlingTime": "1",
      "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
      "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
      "shippingServiceCost": {
        "_currencyId": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
      },
      "shippingType": "Free"
    },
    "title": "3/4/5/6/8inch 110V Magic Crystal Globe Desktop Lightning Lamp Plasma Ball Sphere",
    "user_args": {
      "advanced": null,
      "pages": {
        "entries_per_page": 10,
        "page_number": 10
      },
      "search_terms": "ball"
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know why I am receiving this undefined error, as I made sure to return `response.Object` for the `ajaxResponse`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issue here

Firstly you should generally be returning an array of objects not an object with enumerated properties.

instead of this:

```
{
   {
    "0": {
        "country": "US",
    },
    "1": {
        "country": "CN",
    }
}
```

It should be this:

```
[
    {"country": "US"},
    {"country": "CN"},
]
```

At that point you wouldn't need to use the ***ajaxResponse*** function, tabulator would be able to parse the data directly.

If you can only return the data in that original format there is no problem, but it brings us onto the second issue, the reason you are getting the "undefined error" is because there is no "Object" property on the response object, only the properties "0", "1", "2" etc...

To convert your response to something that Tabulator can understand you will need to use the following ***ajaxResponse*** callback:

```
ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
    return Object.values(response);
}
```

That will convert your returned object of objects into an array of objects.